# how to use feathersjs filter service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, feathersjs

Hi I don't understand what is filter service and how it use. I updated my node, npm package and all node_modules. Now, when I have been creating new service I getting new file and it's look:

```
/* eslint no-console: 1 */
console.warn('You are using the default filter for the users service. For more information about event filters see https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html#event-filtering'); // eslint-disable-line no-console

module.exports = function (data, connection, hook) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  return data;
};
```

how to use it and what the filtering service is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filters service is for filtering the events which are emitted from your service.
For example, let's say you have a Members service. When a member is created in your service the 'created' event will be emitted to all connected users by default. By using filters you can limit which users receive those events - you may want only the users which belong to the same group as the new member to receive that event.
See this link for more details on Events in Feathers https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html

Comment: does the service need to use a socket for this purpose?

Comment: @SeaDog Yes, but it is the other way around. If you use sockets then you will need filters. Because you want to only inform those who needs to be informed for a certain event.

Comment: OK and if my client use callback? so what then? for example: I click on the button on my site. My script call an update method. This method send a data to REST and return result then I receive this result in callback so the result I receive only. I don't understand when should I use the filters?

Comment: If you are using REST then you do not need to worry about the filters as you can only subscribe to the events when you are using websockets.
If you are the one making the API call then you just need to worry about what the data returned in your callback is - no need to worry about events and filters in that case!

Comment: Can you give me simple example or explanation when to use filters? Step by step. When a server send? How the server know who is who?

Comment: Imagine you have a notification bar at the top of your app which shows a red icon with a number if you have unread notifications (like facebook).

Everytime a new notification is created you would like the indicator to update in real-time so you add an event listener on the notification service. (e.g. `app.service.on('created', yourListener)`)

But by default, feathers sends events to all connected users. So you add a filter so that each user only receives events for notifications which belong to them. This would check something like `notification.userId === user.id`

Comment: hope that helps explain things a bit @SeaDog! If you need more help you should join the feathers Slack channel where people (much more experienced than myself) are always willing to help by going here https://slack.feathersjs.com/!
Would also appreciate marking my answer as correct if you think it was useful ;)